# Is this cast in my generic method safe?

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-safety

I have code in my project that looks like this:

```
public interface Bar<T extends Foo<?>> {
 //...
}

public class MyFoo implements Foo<String> {
    private List<Bar<Foo<String>> barFoo = ...

    public <U extends Foo<String>> boolean addBar(Bar<? extends U> b) {
        barFoo.add((Bar<Foo<String>>) b); //safe cast?
    }

}
```

Eclipse gives a warning for the cast in `addBar` that the cast is unsafe.  However, am I correct in assuming that the cast will not throw given the restrictions that I have put on the type parameters, and therefore the cast is indeed safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in general.

Suppose `Bar` has a method `void get(T value)`, and there are two implementations of `Foo<String>`, `MyFoo` and `YourFoo`. Now suppose a caller calls `addBar` on a value of type `Bar<MyFoo>`. This works: when `U` = `Foo<String>`, we have that `Bar<MyFoo>` is a subtype of `Bar<? extends U>`. Now we cast that value to a `Bar<Foo<String>>`.

Now if `Bar` has no methods that accept `T`'s as arguments, there's no problem. But suppose it has a method `void process(T value)`. The implementation we called has `T` = `MyFoo`, so it only has a `process(MyFoo value)` method. Once we cast it to a `Bar<Foo<String>>`, though, we might call it with a `YourFoo` instead. This is illegal.

Stab in the dark, but I suspect that what you really wanted to do was declare `barFoo` as a `List<? extends Bar<? extends Foo<String>>`.

Comment: @DongieAgnir you are probably fine with `List<Bar<? extends Foo<String>>` and `public boolean addBar(Bar<? extends Foo<String>>)`

Answer (score 2):

This is not a safe cast.  Eclipse is correct.

Imagine you has a class `MyFoo` that extends `Foo` and you passed in a `Bar<MyFoo<String>>` Now some method in `Bar` with a `myMethod(Foo x)` signature when only a `myMethod(MyFoo x)` signature was compiled, so the method lookup would fail.

Comment: You can't have a class that extends String, since it's final, can you?

Comment: This is a good point, and is part of how immutability is guaranteed for String.  The same logic applies if you use MyFoo to extend Foo, and we'll assume Foo is not final.

Answer (score 0):

The cast is *not* safe, because although `U` extends `Foo<String>`, it is *not* (necessarily) the case that `Bar<U>` extends `Bar<Foo<String>>`. In fact, `Bar<U>` will only extend `Bar<Foo<String>>` when they are the same thing, i.e., when `U` is `Foo<String>`.

Intuitively, it may seem that (for example) `List<String>` should be a subtype of `List<Object>`, but this is not how generics work. `List<String>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Object>`, but it is *not* a subtype of `List<Object>`. (It may make more sense to consider an example like `Comparable<T>`: `Comparable<String>` means "can be compared to any `String`, whereas `Comparable<Object>` means "can be compared to any `Object`". It should be clear that `Comparable<String>` should not be a subtype of `Comparable<Object>`.)

> […] the cast will not throw […], and therefore the cast is indeed safe?

I think you're misunderstanding the nature of the warning. Eclipse is warning you that this cast will not throw *even when it should*, and this is actually *why* it's not safe. For example, this code:

```
final Object o = Integer.valueOf(7);
final String s = (String) o;
```

is perfectly safe, because the cast will throw an exception. But this code:

```
final List<?> wildcardList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Integer.valueOf(7));
final List<String> stringList = (List<String>) wildcardList;
```

is *unsafe*, because the runtime has no way of checking the cast (due to erasure), so it won't throw an exception, even though it's wrong: `stringList` is now a `List<String>` whose first element is of type `Integer`. (What happens is, at some point later on, you can get a spontaneous `ClassCastException` when you try to do something with that element.)